# how to update the array from one class from another class while pushing

Tags: iphone

```
TestAsyncViewController *detailViewController = [[TestAsyncViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestAsyncViewController" bundle:nil];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

after pushed to TestAsyncViewController class controller view how to update the array in pushed controllers from detailViewController.

specially use of pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete, but you can use:

- Singleton - You can use singleton class to hold your data, observe changes via KVO, ...
- Delegate - delegate of your detailViewController can call pushee controller method to update data,
- CoreData - if you do use CoreData, you can again watch for changes, for example NSFetchedResultsController,
- you can pass your pushee array controller to detailViewController, modify it there and when you're going back to your pushee view controller, you can update its view (viewWillAppear, or delegate, ...)

... There are so many possibilities and it's hard to answer. You should be more specific and show us more code.

The last example can look like ...

```
---- Your pushee view controller implementation

- (void)showAsyncViewController {
  .. array is in __myArray variable ...
  TestAsyncViewController *asyncViewController = [[TestAsyncViewController alloc] ...];
  asyncViewController.data = __myArray;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:asyncViewController];
  [asyncViewController release];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  ... handle changes of __myArrat ...
}

---- interface of TestAsyncViewController

@interface TestAsyncViewController : ... {
  NSMutableArray *__data;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *data;

@end


---- implementation of TestAsyncViewController ...

@implementation TestAsyncViewController

@synthesize data = __data;

... use __data in any of your methods ...

- (void)dealloc {
  [__data release]; __data = nil;
  ...
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Again, it's shot into the dark, because it's **not** absolutely clear what do you want to achieve. Be more specific to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear with the Q but i will tell you bout both the situation ......
Suppose you are at viewController1 and you pushed another viewController2 into navigationController .....

Now if you want to update an array of viewController2 form viewController1 just make that array as a property of viewController2. Then you can directly access that array as

```
viewController2.array
```

now suppose the situation is that you want to access the array of viewController1 form viewController2 ...... simply pass that array to viewController2 and store it in any variable by copy method or can have its reference by retain method.

Comment: i want to update the array in viewcontroller1 from viewcontroller2

Comment: make a property in  viewcontroller2 ........ i hope you know how to make a property .....
Now before this line 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:asyncViewController];
write
viewcontroller2.array = yourArray;